# How to create proto robots in webots

Tags: webots

I am now building the bot using the interface that comes with webots, the bot is functional for my needs, but I need this bot to be displayed on the webots-view and he will load very slowly, <3 minutes per load.
This is my robot, which looks very complex: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEFJ3.png)
My bot scenario is similar to this one: https://youtu.be/Bz-rbW0a1s8.
I see official bots like pr2, moose, etc. They are all much more complex than my bot, but load more than 5 times faster than mine. Can you tell me how the official bots are built?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbIAL.jpg)

Can you tell me how the official bots are built?